# MATLAB: Change font size of command window

Tags: matlab, font-size

I would like to temporarily change the font size of the text in the command window of MATLAB. I am running an experiment in which I am standing at the other side of the lab, and need to occasionally read a number from the screen. I don't want all the MATLAB output to be jumbo size forever - just this one variable when it occasionally comes up. I expect there must be some code that increases font size? I know I can adjust for example font colour using the following code:

```
com.mathworks.services.Prefs.setColorPref('ColorsText',java.awt.Color.red);
com.mathworks.services.ColorPrefs.notifyColorListeners('ColorsText');
```

(The above changes the text in the command window to red). There must be similar code to set font size?

The ideal solution would be a parameter to add to the fprintf command, such that only the one bit of output is larger. However, I would accept a solution in which the entire output of the screen is made larger temporarily...

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about displaying all output in a figure instead of the command line? You could place text-objects and define colors and font sizes.

One way is the following:
"File > Preferences > Fonts > Custom" and there set your font and size. But it's not accessible setting from the commandline itsel so you would have to set it manually and afterwards disable it.

**Edit:**

To pop out a figure and print out a certain variable is easy:

```
foo = 100;
figure
uid = uicontrol('Style', 'text','String', ['FOO = ' num2str(foo)], 'FontSize', 80, 'ForegroundColor', 'b', 'Units','normalized','Position', [0 0 1 1]);
```

you could also specify the position and size of the figure window itself, if you want to.
To close the figure later, just use:

```
delete(gcf);
```

If you want to update the value of it, just use something like

```
set(uid, 'String', 'New text')
```

Comment: Hrm, perhaps having the number pop up in a big box would suffice.. How would I go about popping up a figure that just displays a large number? I presume I could have the figure self-close later on..?

Comment: Thank you. This is a better solution than I had hoped! My number is always an integer between 1 and 20 and just tells me what I ought to be doing on the other side of the lab. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

HOME TAB -> ENVIRONMENT TAB -> Preferences -> Fonts

Comment: Thanks, but I was looking for a programmatic solution.